# this website will not display properly and the text is a problem

Tags: html, css, text

So I have a school project due and my website will not display my text properly. Does anybody know the problem?

Here is the code

```css
body {
  background-image: image();
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  background-color: navy;
  padding: 34px;
}

.homestyle {
  margin: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Prompt', sans-serif;
  float: left;
}

.concertstyle {
  margin: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Prompt', sans-serif;
  float: left;
}

.sportstyle {
  margin: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Prompt', sans-serif;
  float: left;
}

.Receptenstyle {
  margin: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Prompt', sans-serif;
  float: left;
}

.Contactstyle {
  margin: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Prompt', sans-serif;
  float: left;
}

.foto_zwolle {
  width: 150px;
  float: right;
}

.knopanimatie a::after {
  content: '';
  width: 0%;
  height: 2px;
  background: #fff;
  margin: auto;
  transition: 0.5s;
  display: block;
}

.knopanimatie a:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
}

.footer {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Prompt', sans-serif;
  background-color: rgb(21, 108, 179);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  min-height: 0%;
  /* Equal to height of footer */
  /* But also accounting for potential margin-bottom of last child */
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.sticky {
  top: 0;
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 'header header header' 'zwolle zwolle zwolle' 'tekstlinks tekstmidden tekstrechts ' 'footer footer footer';
  gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.tekstlinks {
  grid-area: tekstlinks;
  height: 100px;
  width: 360px;
  padding: 30px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  font-family: 'Prompt', sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
}

.tekstmidden {
  grid-area: tekstmidden;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 360px;
  padding: 30px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  font-family: 'Prompt', sans-serif;
}

.zwolle {
  grid-area: zwolle;
  font-family: 'Prompt', sans-serif;
  padding: 30px;
}

.tekstrechts {
  grid-area: tekstrechts;
  font-family: 'Prompt', sans-serif;
  height: 100px;
  width: 360px;
  padding: 30px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

````html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylejustin.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Prompt:ital,wght@1,100&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <title> Document </title>
</head>
<img class="foto_zwolle" src="logo_rechtop_klein.png" alt="tekst">


<body>
  <header>
    <div class="knopanimatie">
      <a class="homestyle" href="home.html"> Home </a>
      <a class="concertstyle" href="concerten.html"> Concerten </a>
      <a class="sportstyle" href="sport.html"> Sport </a>
      <a class="Receptenstyle" href="Recepten.html"> Recepten </a>
      <a class="Contactstyle" href="contact.html"> Contact </a>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="zwolle">
      <h1> Nieuws uit Zwolle </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="tekstlinks">
      <p> sapien et ligula ullamcorper. In aliquam sem fringilla ut morbius.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tekstmidden">
      <img src="/mainPags/Zwolle+op+hoogte.jpg" width="250px" style="z-index: 20;">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
      </p>
      </p>
      <div class="tekstrechts">
        <p>
          In aliquam sem fringilla ut morbius.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">



    <div class="push"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="sticky">
    <footer class="footer">
      <h3> Footer </h3>
      <p>Footerinfo</p>
      <p> infovanfooter </p>
    </footer>
  </div>

</body>

</html>



```
````

Please note that some of this has been written in dutch, so don't pay attention to it. That is just my main language.

I tried messing with the `padding`, `margin` and even the gridbox but nothing helped. Please help me.

Comment: You have a </p> closing tag on line 38, but no opening tag. `<img src="/mainPags/Zwolle+op+hoogte.jpg" width="250px" style="z-index: 20;">
        <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        </p>
        </p> //<- here
        <div class="tekstrechts">`

Comment: If you have more questions, I can create a chatroom so we can chat. And I'll be able to answer in Dutch, which probably makes it easier to understand :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.